# How to record audio in Windows Server 2008 Web SP2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, audio-recording

I face into this problem and before ask here I've searched and read a lot of question but no-one seems to fit to my problem.

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 Web with the SP2 and a headset attached to it using audio jack. The server has audio driver since I can listen audio. This OS does not  came with the built-in audio record tool (the one I have in Windows 7). I can access physically and remotely (using RDC) to this server with administration permission. My local pc has Windows 7 if it can help.

All I want to do is to know if it's possible and how to record audio form the microphone (of the server) and store that file in the server from remote connection. I tried to install several software on the server but everyone fails with a different issues (missing DLL which if I put in the system the error doesn't go away).

Comment: First thing is to make sure you aren't grabbing the audio with RDesktop.  That could make things really buggy.

Comment: I understand that.  What I meant was that if you're forwarding audio over your remote desktop connection, it could introduce bugs with local capture.

Comment: @aking1012 Now I understand. Well, at the moment I'm forwarding the audio in output from the remote server to the local pc but if I have to disable temporary it, it's not a problem.

Comment: okay.  so you want to do this capture silently?  and do you want to do it in conjunction with screen capture or not so much?

Comment: I don't need to capture the screen, I want just the audio. If for "silently" you mean noone will know it, it's not a problem because of I'm the only person that have access to the server.

Comment: Just to clarify -- You're trying to capture audio to the server, from a microphone that's attached to the server directly?  You're NOT trying to pip the audio over RDP, right?  How is the mic attached (audio jack, USB)? Does the server have audio drivers loaded? Can you record on the server when you are in front of it (taking RDP out of the equation), say by just using Windows in-build sound recorder?  What are some of the specific "issues" that arose when trying to install recording software?

Comment: Can you record sound properly when you are physically in front of the server?

Comment: @techie007 I don't know if I can record because I've not tried yet (I can tomorrow) but the things is that I don't have the built-in software of microsoft and, as I said, other software give me errors. Don't know if it help, but I can talk through Skype.